# Error when using LabelBinarizer for classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a machine learning model that will classify a set of features (locality, minimum price, maximum price, and average rent) to a particular house type (1BHK, 2BHK, 3BHK). 1BHK meaning house with 1 bedroom, hall and kitchen. So my target has three classes (1BHK, 2BHK, 3BHK).

If I use LabelEncoder, I am able to train the model successfully. But if I use LabelBinarizer, I get the below error:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (106,3) instead
```

[Link to dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t94teslzxlq7nj/rentdtls.csv?dl=0)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing  import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder,LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

#convert labels/target to numeric
def convert_labels_to_num(data,method="LE"):
    if method=="LB":                
        lb=LabelBinarizer()     
        lb.fit(data["HouseType"])       
        data=lb.transform(data["HouseType"])
    elif method=="LE":      
        le=LabelEncoder()
        le.fit(data["HouseType"])
        data=le.transform(data["HouseType"])
    return data


#import dataset
data=pd.read_csv("rentdtls.csv",na_values=["-"])
print(data.head())

#==========================================
# Data pre-processing
#==========================================

#Handle NaN value
data=data.dropna()
data.info()
data_bkup=data
    
#Handle categorical value (INPUT FEATURES)
ohe=OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit(data[["Locality"]])
data_new=ohe.transform(data[["Locality"]]).toarray()
data_newdf=pd.DataFrame(data=data_new,columns=ohe.get_feature_names_out())  
#remaining columns
df_price=data[["MinPrice","MaxPrice","AvgRent"]]
#to make it concat friendly     
df_price=df_price.reset_index(drop=True) 

#join input features
inp_feat=pd.concat([data_newdf,df_price],axis=1)

print("Input Features after pre-processing : \n", inp_feat)

# LE for LabelEncoder and LB for LabelBinarizer
label_method="LB"

#Convert label to numeric
if label_method=="LE":
    labels=convert_labels_to_num(data_bkup)
    data_final=pd.concat([inp_feat,pd.Series(labels)],axis=1) 
elif label_method=="LB":
    labels=convert_labels_to_num(data_bkup,"LB")
    data_final=pd.concat([inp_feat,pd.DataFrame(labels)],axis=1)

#Define X and y
if label_method=="LE":
    X=data_final.iloc[:,:-1]
    y=data_final.iloc[:,-1]
elif label_method=="LB":
    X=data_final.iloc[:,:-3]
    y=data_final.iloc[:,58:61]
    
#split data into Train and Test
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=2)

#Train the model
model=SVC()
model.fit(train_x,train_y)

#Predict TEST data
predict_test_y=model.predict(test_x)

#print metrics
print(confusion_matrix(predict_test_y,test_y))
print()
print("Accuracy Score : %.2f "%accuracy_score(predict_test_y,test_y))
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with this part of your code

```
X=data_final.iloc[:,:-3]
y=data_final.iloc[:,58:61]
```

You're passing three columns as Y, I'm guessing that's because you've created three target columns with your BHKs. In sklearn, the original feature structure before you applied the preprocessor persists. Try passing the same X and y as you did with the label encoder.

Comment: If I pass the same X and y as I did for LabelEncoder, it might work but I think it will learn to identify only 3BHK. And I got to know that using LabelEncoder creates some sort of ranking. So I wanted to try out LabelBinarizer. But its not working. We need to somehow let model.fit() know that its a single target  like (n_samples, n_classes)